# Best way to programmatically add tables to node and express app with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have been doing some research on this for a bit but can't seem to find the right answer. I am building a personal bugetting application with node, Express and Sequelize. In order to give users as much flexibility as possible, I want the app to dynamically generate tables for user budgets. Users can create as many budgets as they want, and add up to 10 or 12 columns. I was thinking of using a Sequelize raw query, but dynamically generating the query is messy and I'm not sure it's very good practice. Should I use a migration and the umzug library? The thing is I'm still pretty new to server side development and databases so I just need a bit of guidance on this. Here is my current raw query. I haven't tested it yet as I have been building out other core components of the app.

```js
/* Handle dynamic budget table creation and queries */

const Db = require('./lib/Db.js');

module.exports = class Budget extends Db
{
    /**
     * Create a new budget table
     * @param {String} name - budget name
     * @param {Object} columns - object of column names and their values
     * @param {String} user - user name
     * @param {Number} userId - user id
     */
    async createNewBudget(name, columns, user, userId)
    {
        let query = `CREATE TABLE ${name}_budget (`;
        for (let key in columns) {
            query += `${key} NUMERIC, `;
        }
        query += ")";
        await this.db.sequelize.query(query);
        let insert = `INSERT INTO ${name}_budget(`;
        for (let key in columns) {
            insert += `${key}, `;
        }
        insert += ") VALUES (";
        for (let key in columns) {
            insert += `${columns[key]}, `;
        }
        insert += ")";
        await this.db.sequelize.query(insert);
    }
}
```

The `Db` class is a simple class that makes available the `sequelize` instance:

```js
/* Base class for all classes interacting with the database via raw queries */

module.exports = class Db 
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.db = require('../models/index.js');
    }
}
```

I have these files in my `lib` directory. I just have a feeling that the way I'm going about this isn't that good. Any helpful suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have had the desire to do this myself but haven't been able to spend any time on it.  My mental model was having an interface to create the tables, set the columns and data types, relationships, etc.  This would end up as a JSON object that would be sent to the server.  That object would then be used to create js files with sequelize models in them, or the object would be used to call Sequelize APIs to create the models and then sync the database.  There were too many unknowns for me to justify spending time on it.

Comment: I briefly thought about the idea of just dynamically generating the model files and syncing them similar to what you were thinking, but I think in production that could end up generating a really unwieldy number of files. If your app was even kind of popular, thousands. Sequelize does have apis to alter the database schema itself (like adding tables or columns) but doing it dynamically is the trouble. Not sure the best way. The umzug documentation completely sucks. I browsed through it and didn't understand anything because of my inexperience.

Comment: In my opinion that is not the correct approach. One should create a model like Budget and in case of using a database like Postgres: JSONB ftw.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little curious as to why you want a user to be able to create new tables... I think you should be using migration to setup your original database, and think it through to the point where users have id's, then you have a user_budget table that is a many to many connection to budget an array of options after that, database design does take some planning but it is not rocket science and if/when you don't get it right, it's not too hard to change... postgres, mySQL etc are great at handling scads of rows efficiently and many relationships, but i think you might be creating a bunch of technical debt and non-scalable solution to create new tables for new budgets, that is unnecessary with an RDBMS.  You are creating a new table for something that could just be a couple rows in a well designed DB

Comment: Even if I do what you said, I'd still have to programmatically add columns. Users need to be able to define their own budget categories.

Comment: Actually, I think I'm wrong about that. Thanks for nudging my thinking in another direction.

Comment: right, you need a budget category table that takes something like a budget_id and category_name as a primary key, ofcourse budget_id would be tied to a user through a relation table... This would allow you to create many categories for a budget and you can decide how to customize those categories... Obviously i am way over simplifying, but this can all be done through existing tables with good design and sequelize has been awesome to deal with for CRUD...

Answer (score 1):

We can define the model in one file, say models/budget.js:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {

    const Budget = sequelize.define('budget', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
            primaryKey: true,
        },        
        category: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true,
            defaultValue: null,
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true,
            defaultValue: null,
        },
        ...,
        version: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            defaultValue: 0,
            allowNull: false,
        },
    }, {
        version: true,
        paranoid: true        
    });

    return Budget;
};
```

Then create a ["migrations" file](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/migrations/) which loads the model into the DB:

```
'use strict';

const models = require('../models');

module.exports = {
    up: function (queryInterface) {
        return queryInterface.createTable(models.Budget.tableName, models.Budget.rawAttributes);
    },

    down: function (queryInterface) {
        return queryInterface.dropTable(models.Budget.tableName);
    },
};
```